# css svg animations use up too much server resources

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

Does animation like below drain server resources?

I have many animations of similar(not only in rect but in different shapes too), some have more than 20 `nth-child` up to 8s, I am working on a localhost and it exhausts battery. My laptop is hot while it is on and there is system prompt of the page using up too much resources.

I wonder if it is cause by the animations? if yes, How can I achieve the same result without draining the server resources?

```css
#svg rect {
  --animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation: ani 1.8s linear infinite var(--animation-delay);
}


#svg rect:hover {
  animation:none;

} 


#svg rect:nth-child(2) { --animation-delay: 0.2s; }
#svg rect:nth-child(3) { --animation-delay: 0.3s; }
#svg rect:nth-child(4) { --animation-delay: 0.4s; }
#svg rect:nth-child(5) { --animation-delay: 0.5s; }



@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    fill: #0057B8;
  }

  20% {
    fill: #F11E4A;
  }

  40% {
    fill: #F8A527;
  }

  60% {
    fill: #266D7F;
  }

  80% {
    fill: #82A;
  }

  100% {
    fill: #0057B8;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="401" height="275" viewBox="0 0 401 275" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="401" height="275" fill="white"/>
<rect x="50" y="91" width="57" height="57" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
<rect x="118" y="91" width="57" height="57" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
<rect x="186" y="91" width="57" height="57" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
<rect x="254" y="91" width="57" height="57" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Animation plays on **client** (browser), not on **server**.

Comment: Thanks! @kosh what are the things I can do to make it less resource intensive on browser?

Comment: it's difficult to say without seeing the full picture and understanding what exactly you're trying to build. If you have a lot of elements to animate, _probably_ you'd like to consider `canvas` or `WebGL`.

Comment: @Kosh like the example shown in the question and many of them in a page. Each animation, as example, can be from 5nth-child up to 20nth-child. Animation up to 8s in an infinite loop. Only simple shapes like rect, circles.

Comment: If you're using simple shapes only and not using path or filter animations, you might use HTML instead of SVG. Also, as an optimization, you might temporary disable animation for off-screen elements. Though, it's still not clear to me what you're building =))